# MDM Push notification not arriving on ipad

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am trying to implement MDM solution.
I have MDM server in C#. 
it uses PushSharp lib to send Push Notification.
when i create profile using IPCU and install profile on device by physically connecting it to mac.
profile gets installed without any issue. my profile has MDM payload.
during installation Checkin URL of MDM server gets executed and i do receive Authenticate and TokenUpdate req from deivce. server collects device token and push magic string from req and store it.

Now when i try to send Push notification, Pushsharp lib says its sent but i never receive push notification on ipad side. the reason i m saying this because my Server url is never executed (which should be executed on push arrival).

- I m using PushSharp lib on server side to send push notification.
- My Push pay load is like {"mdm":"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"}
- mdm topic used is from APNS certificate subject. i.e : com.apple.mgmt.External.XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
- p12 file using to send Push is exported from mdm certificate in key chain.

How can i investigate this further; where i m going wrong .
whike creating profile which p12 file i should use for Credentials payload.

please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to do two things. I am not sure how much info PushSharp expose, but I believe APNS give you some report on whether push notification was acccepted by APNS or not. Also, check device console logs (for errors).